Heatmap drilldown is not drilling down correctly and not changing xAxis
I am trying to drilldown my heatmap. The drilldown is not working correctly. The xAxis is remaining the same.
My code:


// Substring template helper for the responsive labels
Highcharts.Templating.helpers.substr = (s, from, length) =>
    s.substr(from, length);

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday',
        style: {
            fontSize: '1em'
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ["Africa","East Asia","English","Eurasia","Latin America","News Network","South & Central Asia"]
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ["Jun 23, 2024","Jun 30, 2024","Jul 7, 2024","Jul 14, 2024","Jul 21, 2024"],
        title: null,
        reversed: true
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormat: '{(add index 1)}. ' +
                '{series.xAxis.categories.(x)} sales ' +
                '{series.yAxis.categories.(y)}, {value}.'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        format: '<b>{series.xAxis.categories.(point.x)}</b> sold<br>' +
            '<b>{point.value}</b> items on <br>' +
            '<b>{series.yAxis.categories.(point.y)}</b>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [{"x":0,"y":0,"value":986122,"name":"Africa","id":"Africa","drilldown":"Africa"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":1346570,"name":"Africa","id":"Africa","drilldown":"Africa"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":3572925,"name":"Africa","id":"Africa","drilldown":"Africa"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":1367264,"name":"Africa","id":"Africa","drilldown":"Africa"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":703258,"name":"Africa","id":"Africa","drilldown":"Africa"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":5265997,"name":"East Asia","id":"East Asia","drilldown":"East Asia"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":6305690,"name":"East Asia","id":"East Asia","drilldown":"East Asia"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":6420835,"name":"East Asia","id":"East Asia","drilldown":"East Asia"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":4388311,"name":"East Asia","id":"East Asia","drilldown":"East Asia"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":1226716,"name":"East Asia","id":"East Asia","drilldown":"East Asia"},{"x":2,"y":0,"value":195536,"name":"English","id":"English","drilldown":"English"},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":226954,"name":"English","id":"English","drilldown":"English"},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":615129,"name":"English","id":"English","drilldown":"English"},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":610941,"name":"English","id":"English","drilldown":"English"},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":281324,"name":"English","id":"English","drilldown":"English"},{"x":3,"y":0,"value":1598662,"name":"Eurasia","id":"Eurasia","drilldown":"Eurasia"},{"x":3,"y":1,"value":2229279,"name":"Eurasia","id":"Eurasia","drilldown":"Eurasia"},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":2101349,"name":"Eurasia","id":"Eurasia","drilldown":"Eurasia"},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":1780694,"name":"Eurasia","id":"Eurasia","drilldown":"Eurasia"},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":556516,"name":"Eurasia","id":"Eurasia","drilldown":"Eurasia"},{"x":4,"y":0,"value":723093,"name":"Latin America","id":"Latin America","drilldown":"Latin America"},{"x":4,"y":1,"value":907773,"name":"Latin America","id":"Latin America","drilldown":"Latin America"},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":474232,"name":"Latin America","id":"Latin America","drilldown":"Latin America"},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":1045556,"name":"Latin America","id":"Latin America","drilldown":"Latin America"},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":297576,"name":"Latin America","id":"Latin America","drilldown":"Latin America"},{"x":5,"y":0,"value":192253,"name":"News Network","id":"News Network","drilldown":"News Network"},{"x":5,"y":1,"value":238947,"name":"News Network","id":"News Network","drilldown":"News Network"},{"x":5,"y":2,"value":324038,"name":"News Network","id":"News Network","drilldown":"News Network"},{"x":5,"y":3,"value":318308,"name":"News Network","id":"News Network","drilldown":"News Network"},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":95326,"name":"News Network","id":"News Network","drilldown":"News Network"},{"x":6,"y":0,"value":12852933,"name":"South & Central Asia","id":"South & Central Asia","drilldown":"South & Central Asia"},{"x":6,"y":1,"value":13149582,"name":"South & Central Asia","id":"South & Central Asia","drilldown":"South & Central Asia"},{"x":6,"y":2,"value":22665161,"name":"South & Central Asia","id":"South & Central Asia","drilldown":"South & Central Asia"},{"x":6,"y":3,"value":13832014,"name":"South & Central Asia","id":"South & Central Asia","drilldown":"South & Central Asia"},{"x":6,"y":4,"value":3531948,"name":"South & Central Asia","id":"South & Central Asia","drilldown":"South & Central Asia"}],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }],
    drilldown: {
          series: [{"id":"Africa","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":3332,"name":"Central Africa"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":6294,"name":"Central Africa"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":19695,"name":"Central Africa"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":20790,"name":"Central Africa"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":12037,"name":"Central Africa"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":23473,"name":"Bambara"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":41649,"name":"Bambara"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":58678,"name":"Bambara"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":82628,"name":"Bambara"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":16658,"name":"Bambara"},{"x":2,"y":0,"value":112507,"name":"English to Africa"},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":96303,"name":"English to Africa"},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":92259,"name":"English to Africa"},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":113810,"name":"English to Africa"},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":81830,"name":"English to Africa"},{"x":3,"y":0,"value":124456,"name":"French to Africa"},{"x":3,"y":1,"value":166013,"name":"French to Africa"},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":203681,"name":"French to Africa"},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":167273,"name":"French to Africa"},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":74951,"name":"French to Africa"},{"x":4,"y":0,"value":19111,"name":"Hausa"},{"x":4,"y":1,"value":38362,"name":"Hausa"},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":118157,"name":"Hausa"},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":29898,"name":"Hausa"},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":27170,"name":"Hausa"},{"x":5,"y":0,"value":227378,"name":"Horn of Africa"},{"x":5,"y":1,"value":449723,"name":"Horn of Africa"},{"x":5,"y":2,"value":498688,"name":"Horn of Africa"},{"x":5,"y":3,"value":343926,"name":"Horn of Africa"},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":179687,"name":"Horn of Africa"},{"x":6,"y":0,"value":15950,"name":"Portuguese"},{"x":6,"y":1,"value":15644,"name":"Portuguese"},{"x":6,"y":2,"value":115051,"name":"Portuguese"},{"x":6,"y":3,"value":146213,"name":"Portuguese"},{"x":6,"y":4,"value":10532,"name":"Portuguese"},{"x":7,"y":0,"value":160832,"name":"Somali"},{"x":7,"y":1,"value":230285,"name":"Somali"},{"x":7,"y":2,"value":335421,"name":"Somali"},{"x":7,"y":3,"value":293554,"name":"Somali"},{"x":7,"y":4,"value":181145,"name":"Somali"},{"x":8,"y":0,"value":35827,"name":"Swahili"},{"x":8,"y":1,"value":85717,"name":"Swahili"},{"x":8,"y":2,"value":40979,"name":"Swahili"},{"x":8,"y":3,"value":26109,"name":"Swahili"},{"x":8,"y":4,"value":11899,"name":"Swahili"},{"x":9,"y":0,"value":263256,"name":"Zimbabwe"},{"x":9,"y":1,"value":216580,"name":"Zimbabwe"},{"x":9,"y":2,"value":2090316,"name":"Zimbabwe"},{"x":9,"y":3,"value":143063,"name":"Zimbabwe"},{"x":9,"y":4,"value":107349,"name":"Zimbabwe"}]},{"id":"East Asia","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":1637453,"name":"Burmese"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":3193859,"name":"Burmese"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":3134798,"name":"Burmese"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":2169916,"name":"Burmese"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":554289,"name":"Burmese"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":3010,"name":"Cantonese"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":4082,"name":"Cantonese"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":4741,"name":"Cantonese"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":5771,"name":"Cantonese"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":2670,"name":"Cantonese"},{"x":2,"y":0,"value":2309054,"name":"Indonesian"},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":1160367,"name":"Indonesian"},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":415791,"name":"Indonesian"},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":182753,"name":"Indonesian"},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":26107,"name":"Indonesian"},{"x":3,"y":0,"value":248758,"name":"Khmer"},{"x":3,"y":1,"value":486007,"name":"Khmer"},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":435036,"name":"Khmer"},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":585874,"name":"Khmer"},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":112914,"name":"Khmer"},{"x":4,"y":0,"value":10248,"name":"Lao"},{"x":4,"y":1,"value":14033,"name":"Lao"},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":23689,"name":"Lao"},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":16521,"name":"Lao"},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":7454,"name":"Lao"},{"x":5,"y":0,"value":571,"name":"Korean"},{"x":5,"y":1,"value":789,"name":"Korean"},{"x":5,"y":2,"value":696,"name":"Korean"},{"x":5,"y":3,"value":916,"name":"Korean"},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":819,"name":"Korean"},{"x":6,"y":0,"value":119340,"name":"Mandarin"},{"x":6,"y":1,"value":43250,"name":"Mandarin"},{"x":6,"y":2,"value":125474,"name":"Mandarin"},{"x":6,"y":3,"value":101757,"name":"Mandarin"},{"x":6,"y":4,"value":31480,"name":"Mandarin"},{"x":7,"y":0,"value":7194,"name":"Thai"},{"x":7,"y":1,"value":6524,"name":"Thai"},{"x":7,"y":2,"value":16384,"name":"Thai"},{"x":7,"y":3,"value":179481,"name":"Thai"},{"x":7,"y":4,"value":75966,"name":"Thai"},{"x":8,"y":0,"value":156084,"name":"Tibetan"},{"x":8,"y":1,"value":216049,"name":"Tibetan"},{"x":8,"y":2,"value":57013,"name":"Tibetan"},{"x":8,"y":3,"value":68467,"name":"Tibetan"},{"x":8,"y":4,"value":31427,"name":"Tibetan"},{"x":9,"y":0,"value":774285,"name":"Vietnamese"},{"x":9,"y":1,"value":1180730,"name":"Vietnamese"},{"x":9,"y":2,"value":2207213,"name":"Vietnamese"},{"x":9,"y":3,"value":1076855,"name":"Vietnamese"},{"x":9,"y":4,"value":383590,"name":"Vietnamese"}]},{"id":"English","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":175297,"name":"Central News"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":216929,"name":"Central News"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":602938,"name":"Central News"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":601442,"name":"Central News"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":275782,"name":"Central News"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":0,"name":"Public Affairs"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":0,"name":"Public Affairs"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":0,"name":"Public Affairs"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":0,"name":"Public Affairs"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":0,"name":"Public Affairs"},{"x":2,"y":0,"value":20239,"name":"Learning English"},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":10025,"name":"Learning English"},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":12191,"name":"Learning English"},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":9499,"name":"Learning English"},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":5542,"name":"Learning English"}]},{"id":"Eurasia","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":299951,"name":"Albanian"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":487000,"name":"Albanian"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":585711,"name":"Albanian"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":443255,"name":"Albanian"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":175131,"name":"Albanian"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":63088,"name":"Bosnian"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":161947,"name":"Bosnian"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":4192,"name":"Bosnian"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":7312,"name":"Bosnian"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":9046,"name":"Bosnian"},{"x":2,"y":0,"value":166269,"name":"Georgian"},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":214615,"name":"Georgian"},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":261562,"name":"Georgian"},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":77146,"name":"Georgian"},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":6463,"name":"Georgian"},{"x":3,"y":0,"value":24095,"name":"Macedonian"},{"x":3,"y":1,"value":41660,"name":"Macedonian"},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":56299,"name":"Macedonian"},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":152667,"name":"Macedonian"},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":22070,"name":"Macedonian"},{"x":4,"y":0,"value":564318,"name":"Armenian"},{"x":4,"y":1,"value":686099,"name":"Armenian"},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":392295,"name":"Armenian"},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":596224,"name":"Armenian"},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":154656,"name":"Armenian"},{"x":5,"y":0,"value":208512,"name":"Russian"},{"x":5,"y":1,"value":236867,"name":"Russian"},{"x":5,"y":2,"value":359173,"name":"Russian"},{"x":5,"y":3,"value":262347,"name":"Russian"},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":146199,"name":"Russian"},{"x":6,"y":0,"value":264090,"name":"Ukrainian"},{"x":6,"y":1,"value":392413,"name":"Ukrainian"},{"x":6,"y":2,"value":427684,"name":"Ukrainian"},{"x":6,"y":3,"value":227860,"name":"Ukrainian"},{"x":6,"y":4,"value":39206,"name":"Ukrainian"},{"x":7,"y":0,"value":8339,"name":"Serbian"},{"x":7,"y":1,"value":8678,"name":"Serbian"},{"x":7,"y":2,"value":14433,"name":"Serbian"},{"x":7,"y":3,"value":13883,"name":"Serbian"},{"x":7,"y":4,"value":3745,"name":"Serbian"}]},{"id":"Latin America","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":201832,"name":"Spanish"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":434860,"name":"Spanish"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":176866,"name":"Spanish"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":488946,"name":"Spanish"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":73171,"name":"Spanish"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":521261,"name":"Creole"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":472913,"name":"Creole"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":297366,"name":"Creole"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":556610,"name":"Creole"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":224405,"name":"Creole"}]},{"id":"News Network","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":192253,"name":"Persian"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":238947,"name":"Persian"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":324038,"name":"Persian"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":318308,"name":"Persian"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":95326,"name":"Persian"}]},{"id":"South & Central Asia","data":[{"x":0,"y":0,"value":4190212,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"x":0,"y":1,"value":3970923,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"x":0,"y":2,"value":4584039,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"x":0,"y":3,"value":4032404,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"x":0,"y":4,"value":1174856,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"x":1,"y":0,"value":100666,"name":"Azerbaijani"},{"x":1,"y":1,"value":256548,"name":"Azerbaijani"},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":304740,"name":"Azerbaijani"},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":119023,"name":"Azerbaijani"},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":15835,"name":"Azerbaijani"},{"x":2,"y":0,"value":44664,"name":"Bangla"},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":50071,"name":"Bangla"},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":870104,"name":"Bangla"},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":1347291,"name":"Bangla"},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":179944,"name":"Bangla"},{"x":3,"y":0,"value":2846549,"name":"Deewa"},{"x":3,"y":1,"value":3192405,"name":"Deewa"},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":11910043,"name":"Deewa"},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":3620057,"name":"Deewa"},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":926139,"name":"Deewa"},{"x":4,"y":0,"value":920303,"name":"Kurdish"},{"x":4,"y":1,"value":2042245,"name":"Kurdish"},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":801176,"name":"Kurdish"},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":633152,"name":"Kurdish"},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":99908,"name":"Kurdish"},{"x":5,"y":0,"value":227898,"name":"Turkish"},{"x":5,"y":1,"value":380037,"name":"Turkish"},{"x":5,"y":2,"value":380962,"name":"Turkish"},{"x":5,"y":3,"value":330915,"name":"Turkish"},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":60388,"name":"Turkish"},{"x":6,"y":0,"value":4474294,"name":"Urdu"},{"x":6,"y":1,"value":3199688,"name":"Urdu"},{"x":6,"y":2,"value":3735431,"name":"Urdu"},{"x":6,"y":3,"value":3704193,"name":"Urdu"},{"x":6,"y":4,"value":1048837,"name":"Urdu"},{"x":7,"y":0,"value":48347,"name":"Uzbek"},{"x":7,"y":1,"value":57665,"name":"Uzbek"},{"x":7,"y":2,"value":78666,"name":"Uzbek"},{"x":7,"y":3,"value":44979,"name":"Uzbek"},{"x":7,"y":4,"value":26041,"name":"Uzbek"}]}],
          borderWidth: 1,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
          },
        },

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: '{substr value 0 1}'
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    
</figure>



Not sure what is wrong as drilldown is set up correctly. Also on a side note, how to only make the xAxis clickable. Do not change the values to links only the xAxis categories.

Could you explain what you mean by saying that drilldown is not working correctly? When I clicked any of your points the chart moved me to the drilldown series. It's looking good.
Also here's a very simple demo with heatmap drilldown series for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xc94b6w0/
series: [{
 colorByPoint: true,
 data: [{
  x: 1,
  y: 0,
  value: 100,
  drilldown: 'A'
 }, {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  value: 10,
  drilldown: 'B'
 }]
}],

About the clickable xAxis if you willing to add some events to the xAxis labels I suggest using custom plugin developed by Blacklabel named custom-events. Here are the docs: https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events

I mean the x-axis is not changing. for example when I click "Africa", x-axis is remaining the same. Instead of changing to "Central Africa" and so forth

The xAxis changes only when the data changes. Take a look at the example below. Initially, the xAxis shows Africa and Asia. When you click the blue or purple rectangle, the xAxis changes to show only Africa because the data in the drilldown series doesn't include any points for Asia. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2cae708k/ Let me know if you have any further questions!
